# ¿Cómo decodifico un String codificado en base64 que contiene letras latinas (á,é,í,ó,ú)?

Tags: c#, .net

¿Cómo decodifico un `string` que contiene un documento XML que en su contenido tiene letas latinas (á,é,í,ó,ú)?

Hasta ahora he intentado esto:

```
xmlBase64 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(XmlDoc));
xmlBase64 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(XmlDoc));
xmlBase64 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(XmlDoc));
xmlBase64 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(XmlDoc));
```

Pero en todos los casos las letras latinas son sustituidas por signos de interrogación `?` o caracteres similares.

Edición:

Este es el [string codificado](https://gist.github.com/monpeco/1cf2b476c08376fe186551d66d770f25)

Este es el  [decodificado](https://gist.github.com/monpeco/6e50760da00c5649878a18ed4e628c65)

Comment: No se de `c#` pero no es utf -8 en la tercera linea del codigo que adjuntastes?

Comment: @Dacoso según este link es `UTF8` https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Yo también sospecho de que el charset `ISO-8859-1` me pueda servir, pero no se como indicar que me decodifique con este.

Comment: Añadelo a tu cabecera de el archivo con el que estas trabajando , asi: http://www.mundolinux.info/img_2.jpg

Comment: Perfecto, déjame intentar eso y te aviso. Muchas gracias por tu interés.

Comment: Realmente esto no tiene nada que ver con base 64. Al decodificar en base 64 recupera el array de bytes original, tu pregunta es  como convertir un array de bytes (venga de dónde venga) en un String.

Comment: @SJuan76 Entiendo, si gustas puedes editar la pregunta para que esté bien redactada (porque la verdad se nota que sabes más de este tema que yo).

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla sería bueno que edites tu pregunta e incluyas la cadena que quieres convertir al menos, sea un `xml` o `string` (original y codificado). Intenté reproducir tu problema y no tuve los problemas que indicas, debe ser otro el problema que tienes. Revisa: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7fFWZc

Comment: @Davlio agregado links a lo que solicitas. Muchas gracias por dotnetfiddle, yo he utilizado un decodificador online y también lo decodifica sin problemas (con UTF-8).

Comment: @Dacoso Añadí el `ENCODING='ISO-8859-1'` a la cabecera y tampoco soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tú XML está codificado con el sgte encoding: `ISO-8859-1`

Simplemente crea un `Encoding` pasándole ese código como parámetro y con eso ya puedes decodificar el `byte[]`

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(XmlDoc);
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var decoded = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto. En SO en inglés me dieron una respuesta similar a la tuya, pero con el encoding `Windows-1252`.